# Change permissions of windows mounted folder from linux

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, mountpoint

I mounted windows share to linux(rhel7) using

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password> //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt
```

I successfully mounted it. From Linux I tried to change permissions on the mounted folder then it gave me the error.

**chmod: changing permissions of ‘/mnt/’: Permission denied**

```
chmod -R 777 /mnt
```

How can I change permissions of the mounted folder in Linux?

Is it possible to change permission on the mounted windows folder from Linux command(chmod)?

Comment: Also note that Ask Ubuntu is for Ubuntu related questions you might want to see https://unix.stackexchange.com for RHEL related questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to change permission on the mounted windows folder from
>   Linux command(chmod)?

No. CIFS much like NTFS is a virtual filesystem so chmod has no affect. And changing the permission of the mount point before anything is mounted to it will have no affect either since the permissions after a mount always replace the permissions before the mount.

If the desired permissions is 777 change your mount command to include those permissions: `dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777`. I would also get in the habit of adding the `nounix` option although for a Windows share it won't do much.

So try this instead:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,nounix //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt
```

And I would agree that a better mount point would be something under /mnt rather than /mnt itself.

Comment: It I tries to change permissions on /mnt/ using chmod 777 /mnt  it is giving error permission denied. But If I make new folder in /mnt say /mnt/share then If I tries to change permissions using chmod 777 /mnt/share It is not theowing any error but permissions were not getting changed. Why  is this happening?

Comment: /mnt Which I mentioned in the question is in /home/mnt not directly /mnt.

Comment: @Morbius1 What does `,` do? I can't find `dir_mode` or `file_mode` or `nounix` in manual pages of `mount`

Comment: Ohhhh... I should separate the options with `,`. I found it in `man mount.cifs`. I first had to find which manpage, `man -K file_mode` worked nicely.

Comment: i just added `dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777` as instructed and my mount folder is now writable. [+1]

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, only root (by default) may change permissions to the `/mnt` directory itself since it's owned by `root:root` - so attempting to modify it's permissions will fail as non-root.

You likely want to make this easier on yourself by creating a subdirectory inside `/mnt`, changing it's permissions, then mounting there.

First unmount anything already:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Next create a subdirectory where you will mount the share

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/share
```

Now change the permissions to be owned by the user you want to modify it:

```
sudo chown foo:foo /mnt/share
```

Where `foo:foo` is for the user `foo`, which should be your username.

Lastly mount to the `/mnt/share` location instead:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxx //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt/share
```

If you still have problems with the files inside `/mnt/share` not being owned by the correct user you might need to specify the `uid=xxx,gid=xxx` in the mount options.

Comment: I am trying to change permissions using the root user only

Comment: @what's `xxx` in `uid` and `gid`?

Comment: Ohhh it's user id and group id. `id -u` and `id -g`. works nicely

Comment: You can just use set the `uid` and `gid` to the actual name of the user and group respectively, you don't have to manually resolve this to a number. It's not 1978.