# mount permissions from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I have followed [this guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/mount-windows-10-share-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/) in order to share my windows server files with my ubuntu 20.04 box.

It seems to have worked, as long as i am using the `sudo` command when making any changes to files or creating/deleting

if i attempt anything such as `mkdir` without `sudo` then i get permission denied

when the windows share is not mounted, the permissions for `/mnt/winshare` are `drwxrwxrwx 2 user user`

However, when i mount the windows share, they become `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root`

what am i missing?

Comment: You will have to set the proper permissions. Include details of your current setup in your post (use "edit")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change permissions of windows mounted folder from linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104865/change-permissions-of-windows-mounted-folder-from-linux)

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104865/change-permissions-of-windows-mounted-folder-from-linux). I did not do enough digging/google fu was weak!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that you had a samba share, not a physical mount. I deleted my answer, because it is not valid for a cifs mount. – Maybe you should've made that point clearer.